# how to connect markers with lines when drawing scatterplots using matplotlib in the pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I drew a scatterplot using the matplotlib library of Pandas, and I want to connect the markers with the same name with each other.

I want the color of the line connecting the markers to be different in proportion to the distance between the two markers of the same name.

And I want to set the thickness of the line according to the distance of two markers of the same name.

How should I modify the code to make it work the way I want it to?

my code is

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'population' : [673507,341649,408147,603611,548160,322915,371063,409385,431920,386359,364338], 'number' : [1586,858,1068,1617,1906,1265,1581,1780,1879,1935,2003], 'error' : [1408.212414,1189.619423,1169.298565,1177.840805,730.672166,729.182492,550.520026,460.829841,426.108759,240.150393,109.337611], 'index' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'], 'ratio' : [0.235484,0.251135,0.261670,0.267888,0.347709,0.391744,0.426073,0.434799,0.435034,0.500830,0.549764]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'population' : [667480,353241,418620,595691,578221,334426,375180,412774,463321,398351,373824], 'number' : [974,515,872,909,1342,691,746,993,1027,1009,1437], 'error' : [835.205610,672.395313,444.766064,758.150870,290.581558,459.164541,484.807799,312.198108,378.219572,267.658143,208.875429], 'index' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'], 'ratio' : [0.145922,0.145793,0.208303,0.152596,0.232091,0.206623,0.198838,0.240567,0.221661,0.253294,0.384405]})

df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df1.set_index('index', inplace=True)

pf = np.polyfit(df['population'], df['number'], 1)   

fy = np.poly1d(pf)                    
fy    

fx = np.linspace(100000, 700000, 100)  

pf1 = np.polyfit(df1['population'], df1['number'], 1)

fy1 = np.poly1d(pf1)                    

fx1 = np.linspace(100000, 700000, 100)  

x1 = df1
y1 = df1
x2 = df
y2 = df

x1 = x1.reset_index()
x1 = x1.sort_values(by='index', ascending=True)
x1 = x1.drop(['index'], axis=1)
x1 = x1.reset_index(drop=True)

x2 = x2.reset_index()
x2 = x2.sort_values(by='index', ascending=True)
x2 = x2.drop(['index'], axis=1)
x2 = x2.reset_index(drop=True)

y1 = y1.reset_index()
y1 = y1.sort_values(by='index', ascending=True)
y1 = y1.drop(['index'], axis=1)
y1 = y1.reset_index(drop=True)

y2 = y2.reset_index()
y2 = y2.sort_values(by='index', ascending=True)
y2 = y2.drop(['index'], axis=1)
y2 = y2.reset_index(drop=True)


plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))

plt.scatter(df['population'], df['number'], c=df['error'], s=2000*df['ratio']) 

plt.plot(fx1, fy1(fx1), ls='solid', lw=3, color='g')

for n in range(len(df)):
    plt.text(df['population'][n] + 5000,
    df['number'][n] - 20,
    df.index[n],
    fontsize=15)

plt.scatter(df1['population'], df1['number'], c=df1['error'], s=2000*df1['ratio'], alpha=0.5)

plt.plot(fx, fy(fx), ls='dashed', lw=3, color='g', alpha=0.3)

for n in range(len(df1)):
    plt.text(df1['population'][n] + 5000,
    df1['number'][n] - 20,
    df1.index[n],
    fontsize=15)

plt.colorbar()

plt.plot([x1['population'], x2['population']], [y1['number'], y2['number']], c='r', linewidth=10, alpha=0.5)

plt.title('Plot')    
plt.xlabel('Population')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.ylim(0,6000)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZwgV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the last plot command, is a list of the individual lines that are drawn. (Optionally, the z-order can be set to zero, so the lines appear behind the scatter dots. Leaving out the alpha makes the lines more visible.)

`np.linalg.norm` called on the difference between the coordinates can calculate the lengths of the lines.

`plt.Normalize(vmin=..., vmax=...)` creates a function that linearly maps its input values such that `vmin` will be mapped to zero and `vmax` to 1. This can be used to convert a length to a value between 0 and 1 for a colormap. It also can be used to calculate a variable thickness.

Looping through the lines and their respective lengths can set a specific color and thickness:

```py
lines = plt.plot([x1['population'], x2['population']], [y1['number'], y2['number']], zorder=0)
lengths = nplinalg.norm(np.vstack([x1['population'] - x2['population'], x1['number'] - x2['number']]), axis=0)
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=distances.min(), vmax=distances.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')
for line, length in zip(lines, lengths):
    line.set_color(cmap(norm(length)))
    line.set_linewidth(2 + 9 * norm(length))
```

[image: resulting plot]